# Modify all selected cells in a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt

1. It is a standard QTableWidget
2. All cells are QTableWidgetItem.
3. All cells are editable/selectable

Question: How can I modify all the cells I have selected?

Comment: And how do you want to modify them? Programmatically or by the user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem a couple years ago and I solved it like this:

- I have inherited my own view and I have reimplemented methods commitData() and mouseReleaseEvent().
- commitData takes all selected indices from the selection model and calls QAbstractItemModel::setData() for all of them. Data are taken from the editor like this:

`QByteArray n = editor->metaObject()->userProperty().name();`

```
if (n.isEmpty())
    n = delegate->itemEditorFactory()->valuePropertyName(model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).userType());

if (!n.isEmpty())
{
    QVariant data = editor->property(n);

    for (const QModelIndex & idx : selectedIndices)
    {
        model()->setData(idx, data);
    }       
}
```

- mouseReleaseEvent() performs three steps:

  1. Get a current selection from the selection model.
  2. Call original event handler (QTableWidget::mouseReleaseEvent())
  3. Restore selection: QItemSelectionModel::select()

Answer (score 1):

Possible way is to use the dialog open. So the idea is like this :

1. Select the items
2. Make a button or something to open input dialog.
3. Apply the value of input dialog to all selected items.